# How to disable CGO for running tests

Tags: docker, go

I use Docker to add my project to it, now I want to run some test on it and I got errors that the test failed

Any idea what I miss here?

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.11.1-alpine3.8 AS builder

RUN apk add --update --no-cache make \
    git

ADD https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.5.0/dep-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/dep
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/dep

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.company/user/go-application
WORKDIR  $GOPATH/src/github.company/user/go-application
COPY Gopkg.toml Gopkg.lock ./
RUN dep ensure --vendor-only
COPY . ./
```

Now I build the docker which finish successfully and now I want to run tests on it.

I did docker run `docker run -it goapp` which run successfully

And now I use command `go test -v ./...` and I got error

```
# runtime/cgo
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
FAIL    github.company/user/go-application [build failed]
FAIL    github.company/user/go-application/integration [build failed]
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

I try another step in docker file like following which doesnt helps

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix nocgo -o /go-application .
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've disabled CGO for your build, but you're not disabling CGO for your tests, which you must do:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go test -v ./...
```